# Limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan3x}{\sin2x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan3x}{\sin2x}$= $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin(3x)}{\cos(3x)}}{\sin2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin3x}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(3x)}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin(2x)}$

From this point I am lost. I believe I can pull a 3 and 2 out but I am not sure how. Can someone give me detailed instructions for a person in Calculus 1?

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan3x}{\sin2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan3x}{3x}\frac{2x}{\sin2x}\frac{3x}{2x}=\frac{3}{2}$

or by using L'Hôpital's rule
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan3x}{\sin2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3(1+\tan^2 3x)}{2\cos2x}=\frac{3(1+\tan^2 3(0))}{2\cos2(0)}=\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Can you tell rather than show? Does the 3x in the denominator cancel out the tan(3x)? If so, why.

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule is also useful.

Comment: see $\lim_{u\to o}\frac{\tan u}{u}=1=\lim_{u\to o}\frac{\sin u}{u}$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan x}{x} = 1$

Rewrite your expression as

$$\frac{\tan 3x}{x} \cdot \frac{x}{\sin 2x} = \frac 32 \cdot \frac{\tan 3x}{3x} \cdot \frac{2x}{\sin 2x}$$

See what to do now?

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin3x}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(3x)}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin(2x)}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin3x}{3x}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(3x)}\cdot\frac{3x}{\sin(2x)}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin3x}{3x}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(3x)}\cdot\frac{\frac{3}{2}2x}{\sin(2x)}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin3x}{3x}\cdot\frac{1}{cos(3x)}\cdot\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}}$$