# Limit $\lim_{u\to0} \frac{3u}{\tan 2u}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I’m currently stuck trying to evaluate this limit,
$$
\lim_{u\to0} \frac{3u}{\tan(2u)},
$$
without using L’Hôpital’s rule. I’ve tried both substituting for $\tan(2u)=\dfrac{2\tan u}{1-(\tan u)^2}$, and $\tan 2u=\dfrac{\sin 2u}{\cos 2u}$ without success. Am I on the right path to think trig sub?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the limit: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1.$?

Comment: Sorry all, limit as u goes to 0. D.B. yes, that trigonometric limit has been covered and can be used.

Comment: Why not apply the definition $$
\lim_{u \to a}\frac{f(u) - f(a)}{u-a}=f'(a)
$$ to $f(u):=\tan(2u)$ and $a:=0$?

Comment: Ok.  So you can transform your limit into one involving the limit just mentioned by using the fact that $\tan(x) = \sin(x)/\cos(x)$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran Thanks for your help with editing posts. I will point out that neither `\displaystyle` nor `\dfrac` should be used in the titles. For more details, see here: [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9687)

Comment: Olivier Oloa, I think that’s the route I need to go down, I just didn’t see that. Thank you, I’m going to stare at that now

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I shall keep it in mind next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan3x}{\sin2x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467848/limit-lim-x-to-0-frac-tan3x-sin2x)

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{3u}{\tan(2u)}=\frac{3}{2}\times\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{2u}{\sin(2u)}\times\lim_{u\to 0}\cos(2u).
$$
Now use your knowledge of well-known limits.

Answer (score 3):

Because of Taylor series, $\tan2u\sim2u, \quad u\to0$. Then

$$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{3u}{2u}=\frac32$$

Answer (score 2):

The key point is the strandard limit as $x\to 0 \,\frac{\sin x}x\to 1$, indeed we have that

$$\dfrac{3u}{\tan(2u)}=\dfrac{3u}{2u}\dfrac{2u}{\tan(2u)}=\dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{2u}{\sin(2u)}\cos (2u)\to \frac32\cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \frac32$$

with your first idea we obtain

$$\dfrac{3u}{\tan(2u)}=\dfrac{3u}{2\tan(u)}(1-(\tan u)^2))=\frac32\frac u {\sin u}\cos u(1-(\tan u)^2))\to \frac32\cdot 1\cdot1\cdot 1=\frac32$$

Refer to the related

- [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/505767)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{3u}{\tan(2u)}&=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{3u\cos(2u)}{\sin(2u)}\\
&=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{3\cos(2u)}{2}\cdot\frac{2u}{\sin(2u)}\\
&=\left(\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{3\cos(2u)}{2}\right)\cdot \left(\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{2u}{\sin(2u)}\right)\qquad\text{since both limits exist}\\
&=\frac{3}{2}\cdot 1\\
&=\frac{3}{2}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just Taylor the $\tan(2u)$ and the answer comes straight away after you divide by $u$ both the numerator and denominator. This is assuming that $u$ tends to $0$. With infinity limit does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{u\to0} \frac{3u}{\tan(2u)} = \frac{3}{2}\cdot\lim_{u\to0} \bigg[\frac{2u}{\sin(2u)}\cdot\cos (2u)\bigg]$$

Recall that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

and apply it here.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {3x\over \tan 2x}=\lim_{x\to 0} {3x\cos 2x\over \sin 2x}=\lim_{x\to 0} {3x\over \sin 2x}={3\over 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

By MVT

$$\tan(2u)-\tan(0)=$$
$$(2u-0)\Bigl(1+\tan^2(c)\Bigr)=$$

$$2u(1+\tan^2(c))$$

when $u\to 0, \; c\to 0$.

the limit is then
$$\frac 32$$